# How do i change this?? Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[image]

My Minecraft looks like this its supposed to be black and red carpet how do i  fix this i tried F4 and Fn but it just turns my computer screen off i also tried the 3d settings but it was already off,Restarting also isnt working.This is on 1.12.2 and its everywhere on my singleplayer and on my multi

Comment: This is an April fools day thing.  Look at the duplicate question for more details.

Answer (score 1):

It's an April Fools Day thing, remove it by going to a version lower than 1.12 or by downloading Optifine.